# how to use for each ....next for textbox in vb.net

Tags: html, sql, vb.net

I want to use "for each  .... next" to execute my query via textbox,so i want to input values in textbox but i get just one value of the multiple values of textbox

```
Try

    For Each i In TextBox2.Text
        'Create the SelectCommand.

        cmd = New OdbcCommand("select b.id_detail_polygon,b.mappe_3,b.type_d_affaire,b.consistance,b.nbr_borne ,num_bornes,a.x,a.y,b.superficie_cs  from point a right join (select (dp).path[1] d1,(dp).path[2] d2,(dp).geom d3 from (select st_dumppoints(geom) dp from polygon where id_detail_polygon ='" & i & "')a)dptable on st_equals(a.geom,dptable.d3),polygon b where id_detail_polygon='" & i & "' limit ((select st_npoints(geom) from polygon where id_detail_polygon ='" & i & "')-1)", cnDb) ' & _
        adDb = New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)
        adDb.Fill(dsDB, ComboBox1.Text)
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dsDB
        DataGridView2.DataMember = ComboBox1.Text
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dsDB.DefaultViewManager

    Next

Catch ex As Exception
     MsgBox("ERROR :" + ex.Message)
Finally

End Try
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6Mb.jpg)

Comment: please take the [tour] and check [ask] and also go and check the basics of programming and the msdn and you'll learn a textbox control returns a string of all it's content.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Maybe you wont have to create new accounts every week

Comment: TextBox2.Text will have the whole string you enter on the textbox. You would need to split by comma and also add some logic to protect against non integer values.

Comment: read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-each-next-statement and you will realise `For Each` only operates on _collections_, not strings. The output of a textbox's .Text property is a string containing all the contents of the textbox at that moment. Research the string split function instead to split your string up by commas into an array. Then remember to sanitise your input and use SQL parameters to guard against injection attacks from malicious input.

Comment: P.S. Your query is hard to read but a cursory glance suggests you may have a horrific data structure, if you have to inject the same value multiple times into the query to get the right output. Either that or you aren't using joins properly. Also consider whether this could be done in one statement via an "IN" clause rather than running multiple queries in a loop.

Comment: How do you expect the data in the textbox to be formatted?

Comment: @ADyson I looked closer at the sql, and the GIS functions make this necessarily awkward.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how the data in the TextBox will work. You need to be more specific. Is it comma-delimited? Space delimited?

I'm gonna assume comma-delimited. This code should get you started:

```vb
Dim IDs() As Stringg
Dim sql As String = _
     "select b.id_detail_polygon,b.mappe_3,b.type_d_affaire,b.consistance,b.nbr_borne, num_bornes,a.x,a.y,b.superficie_cs " & _
     "from point a " & _
     "right join ( " & _
         "select (dp).path[1] d1,(dp).path[2] d2,(dp).geom d3 " & _
         "from ( " & _
             "select st_dumppoints(geom) dp " & _
             "from polygon " & _
             "where id_detail_polygon= ? " & _
         ") a " & _
      ") dptable on st_equals(a.geom,dptable.d3)" & _ 
      "inner join polygon b on id_detail_polygon= ? " & _ 
      "limit (select st_npoints(geom) from polygon where id_detail_polygon= ? )-1"


DataGridView2.DataMember = ComboBox1.Text
DataGridView2.DataSource = dsDB.DefaultViewManager

Using fields As New TextFieldParser(TextBox.Text), _
      cmd As New OdbcCommand(sql, cnDb), _
      adDb As New OdbcDataAdapter(cmd)      

    fields.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    'Guessing at parameter type here: an id value is usually an int
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.Int)

    ' We know in advance there's only one row
    IDs = fields.ReadFields()
    ' but loop through ALL of the fields in that row
    For Each ID As Integer In IDs.Select(Function(i) Integer.Parse(i))
        cmd.Parameters(0) = ID
        cmd.Parameters(1) = ID
        cmd.Parameters(2) = ID 

        adDb.Fill(dsDB, ComboBox1.Text) 
        DataGridView2.DataSource = dsDB  
    Next Id

End Using
```

But it still has one important flaw. **The datagridview will only show info for the *last* record in your textbox**, because each iteration of the loop overwrites the data from the previous iteration.

I can't fix that problem for you in the context of this question. That's gonna require you to go back to the drawing board on the whole design for this section of the application.

Comment: i use textbox just for determine the values i want to execute